# How to cite all references in a .bib file when having multiple ones

Tags: latex, biblatex

I have added multiple .bib files each holds references relative to a certain topic

```latex
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  citestyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[label=topic1]{topic1.bib}
\addbibresource[label=topic2]{topic2.bib}
\addbibresource[label=topic3]{topic3.bib}
```

I cite most of the time referecnes in each file collectively

```latex
%keys 1 to 5 are in topic1
\cite{key1, key2, key3, key4, key5}
%keys 6 to 12 are in topic2
\cite{key6, key7, key8, key9, key10, key11, key12}
%keys 13 to 15 are in topic3
\cite{key13, key14, key15}
```

but I also cite references from different files

```latex
\cite{key3, key4, key12, key13, key15}
```

Is there a way to cite all to cite all refs fro the same file(topic).